# How to query nested json strings in jsonb field in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, json

In our database, one JSONB column contains an object which has a property which is a string encoded JSON object. I need to deserialize this string during the query and inspect its values.

```
create table datas (id int, data jsonb);
insert into datas (id, data) values (1, '{"key1": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}');
```

I can select the string value, but then casting that into a JSONB object doesn't work. These queries all return null for the `foo`.

```
select data->'key1'->'foo' from datas;
select to_json(data->'key1')->'foo' from datas;
select (data->'key1')::jsonb->'foo' from datas;
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9c0a9f7f1323a35051daba5177e52f57

Comment: `'{"key1": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'` is "wrong". I guess it should be: `'{"key1": {"foo": "bar"}}'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's not wrong, it's the way the data is modelled in our database. It's not a great model, but I'm stuck with it for now.

Comment: Well, in the value `'{"key1": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'` the value of `key1` is a single string, **not** a JSON structure. That's why `data->'key1'->'foo'` doesn't work. As you seem to expect the value of `key1` to be a nested `JSON` you have to get rid of the additional double quotes. `'{"key1": {"foo": "bar"}}'` -> 'key1' -> 'foo'` will work as expected. Your value  `'{"key1": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'` is essentially the same structure as `'{"key1": "some string with the words foo and bar"}'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I realize this is a string and not jsonb. The question is how to deserialize the string (which does contain valid json within it). If the answer is "it can't be done" well, that's an answer at least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need extract the value as `text` using the `->>` operator, only then can you cast it back to a `json` or `jsonb` value:

```
select (data ->> 'key1')::json ->> 'foo'
from datas
```

But the correct solution is to not store the value in a way that you need to cast back and forth every time you access it.

This is because when you cast a `json` (or `jsonb`) to `text` all quotes are kept. And if you cast `'"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"'` back to JSON it's still a single JSON string, not a key/value pair. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ff5d13c0fe20181bbc5212dbfd4c6527)

```sql
create table datas (id int, data jsonb);

insert into datas (id, data) 
values 
  (1, '{"key1": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'), 
  (2, '{"key1": "some thing"}');

select (data->'key1')::text, 
       ((data->'key1')::text)::json,
       data->>'key1'
from datas;
```

| text | json | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" | "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" | {"foo": "bar"} |
| "some thing" | "some thing" | some thing |

Comment: Thank you! This is an existing database I've inherited, and we'll fix the schema when we can. Can you explain a little bit in your answer why the `->>` operator works but the `->` operator doesn't?  This query that I thought would be equivalent doesn't work: `select ((data->'key1')::text)::json->>'foo' from datas;`?

Comment: Because when you cast a `json` (or `jsonb`) to `text` all quotes are kept.  And if you cast `'"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"'` back  to JSON it's still a _single_ JSON string, not a key/value pair. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ff5d13c0fe20181bbc5212dbfd4c6527)